# JavaFX TextArea onChange event

Tags: components, textarea, javafx

Good day developers :)

Does JavaFX component, TextArea, have support for some event like onTextChange or similar?
Yes, I know for keyPressed, keyTyped ... but how to handle event if another "action" do changes on TextArea (eg. txArea.setText("some text")).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As with all of JavaFX, just add a listener to the TextArea `textProperty()`.

Answer (score 55):

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

    textArea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, final String oldValue, final String newValue) {
            // this will run whenever text is changed
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 vote.
I prefered your answer than the one above for the code sample. Rushing to give the fastest answer is not always good.

Comment: Is it possible to add this in SceneBuilder, or just in code?

Answer (score 8):

Using Lambda expressions

```
textArea.textProperty().addListener((obs,old,niu)->{
    // TODO here
});
```

Comment: I felt weird about this one until I realized the change listener is the only thing a property expects for addListener. Though I would prefer (observable, oldVal, newVal) to be a bit more self-documenting.