# JavaFX TextArea Text Modification Listener: Resource Consumption Dilemma

Tags: java, javafx

We are able to handle changes made in the JavaFX TextArea as demonstrated here:
[JavaFX TextArea onChange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863047/javafx-textarea-onchange-event)

Essentially, this 'listener' helps me examine text before & after changes made to the TextArea.

Sometimes, examining only one character is simply enough, but the way the aforementioned method is implemented, it grabs the entire String for before & after. For instance, I wish to implement a persistent indent, and my logic is:

1. I keep a tab counter with initial value of 0.
2. If a `\t` character is entered, then I increment the value each time.
3. Upon input of a `\n`, that many `\t` characters are pre-placed in the following line.
4. If a `BACKSPACE` key is pressed (for simplicity let's consider this as the only option to remove text), then I examine the previous character and if it was a `\t` then I decrement the value each time and so on.

However, I feel that Java grabbing the entire text content as before & after values uses too much resource as opposed to just grabbing one character. So,

- In practice, how much difference does this actually make? I would assume this would be quite resource intensive at levels where a text file is around only 0.5MB or so.
- Is there any other way to implement the listener such that it works the way I want, the current method will not accept anything other than an ObservableList object containing Strings only.

Comment: Using a listener is completely the wrong approach for this. Use a `TextFormatter` instead, and implement the filter. Note that the logic probably needs to be somewhat more complex than you've described (either way you handle it); e.g. consider what happens if a chunk of text is selected, and another chunk of text is copied in.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but how are the two interfaces different from each other in how they work at the semi-machine level? There is still text comparison going on?

Comment: Yes the described logic was just to explain the situation.

Comment: The text formatter's filter is passed a `Change` instance, representing the proposed change in the text. It's not really clear what you're concerned about here; however, the approach you're using: "Let the user change the text and then if that change doesn't turn out to be what you want, change the text again" is clearly inelegant. Intercepting the proposed change and modifying the change before it's applied to the text is exactly what the text formatter is designed for.

Comment: The thing is, I am only comparing two characters in my logic. I am assuming this is less resource intensive than comparing entire texts. The thing I am concerned about is I don't want any inferface to instruct the machine to compare the entire text to detect changes, just the most recently entered or removed character. I am mainly concerned with resource consumption here. The persistent indentation logic is not important to me at this stage.

Comment: I don't understand why you think "resources" are an issue; that doesn't make any sense. It's just clearly not a good approach to make two changes to the text area's text to implement a single change. But as I said in the previous comment, the filter receives a `Change` object encapsulating the *proposed change* in the text; so surely that would address your concern even if it made sense.

Comment: It makes sense I am concerned about it because resources are limited. If resources wasn't concerning, then people would always use linear search instead of binary, for example. I don't fully comprehend how much of a task would become a big deal to a modern processor. Would you elaborate on why you're less concerned with the resources?

Comment: Aside from that, I will look further into your approach. Kindly post your answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thank you.

Comment: In general, you should strive to write the cleanest and most logical code, and only worry about performance if you have actual evidence it is a problem. In this case, using a text formatter is the most logical thing to do anyway. But what resources are you worried about? The worst case is that you retain a copy of the old text for the brief time that the event listeners are being invoked. That's it. There are no other additional "resources" that wouldn't be used anyway.

Comment: My concern is mainly that if the text in the TextArea is very large, this would occupy space in the program stack and comparison performed by the processor would take longer and thus "hold it up".

Comment: *"to instruct the machine to compare the entire text to detect changes"* Nothing "instructs the machine" to compare anything. If you write code to compare something, then that code gets executed. I don't know what you mean by this. And *"just the most recently entered or removed character"* As I keep on saying, the text formatter receives a `Change` *encapsulating the change in the text*. Which is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I respectfully disagree that cleanest and logical code is top priority. Because, I can be very clean and print the number 1 through 100 individually in order. But efficiency is the main reason we use and research into computer logic. I am still a novice, so I would appreciate your insight on this matter if you have time as well.

Comment: This is a principle that has been in practice for about three decades. You can disagree all you like, but if you're a novice and in disagreement with the entire industry, I'd humbly suggest you draw your own conclusion.

Comment: Well, the code being executed carries out those tasks by instructing changes in the registers, performing kernel calls, and updating stack vars, no?

Comment: The relevant key and mouse listener implementations implemented by the text area probably go something like this: when a key is typed, store the current text using `String oldText = getText();`, change the text by inserting text at the caret, then invoke `changed(textProperty(), oldText, getText())` on each `ChangeListener`. **If** this is implemented internally by lazily creating `oldText` only if a change listener exists, then you save the allocation of that variable, which is still pretty negligible. But it's likely not implemented that way.

Comment: Understood. This answers my questions. If you want to you can post the answer and I will mark it as correct. I will be going the TextFormatter route you've suggested. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Here's a good overview of the "premature optimization" discussion: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil (I was wrong about "three decades. It's four. ;) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `ChangeListener` on the text area's `textProperty()` is not the supported way to do what you want. It creates unnecessarily complex logic: by modifying the text inside a listener on the `textProperty()`, you cause another change to the property to be fired while the property itself is being changed. In short, you react to the user changing the text (the actual property has been changed) to then modify the text again to represent what you want.

As an example, if you have a different listener registered with the `textProperty()`, or a binding to it, that listener or binding would observe two changes to the text: the first ("invalid" in the sense of what you want the text to look like) caused by the user, and the second, reverting to what you actually want it to be, caused by the code in your listener.

It's not clear what "resources" you are referring to: in the worst case scenario I could only see an additional, very temporary, copy of the text in the text area; but even that seems quite unlikely - that (temporary) copy likely exists anyway.

So the reason not to use a listener on the `textProperty()` has nothing to do with machine resources or performance; it has to do with the logic of your application and the sequence of values you want the `textProperty()` to assume. You want that property to take, in turn, the values seen by the end user, and never to take the values you want to "correct" with your code.

The way to implement that is to use a `TextFormatter`:

```
textArea.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(change -> {
    // examine change and modify it if necessary...
    return change ;
}));
```

The filter provided to the `TextFormatter` constructor takes a [`TextFormatter.Change`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.Change.html) object that encapsulates the proposed change in the text (i.e. the proposed difference between the current text and the new text). This is invoked before the actual text is modified. This means that in your implementation you can modify that change if necessary, which is exactly your use case. (You can veto the change entirely, i.e. disallow the change, by returning `null`.) Using this approach, the text area's `text` property will transition from the current value to the value represented by the user's input plus the modifications your code makes, with no intermediate values.

See the documentation linked above for the details of how to use the `TextFormatter.Change` object.